# how to "pixelate" a shape in sketch

Tags: sketch-app, pixelation, pixel-art

I am new to Sketch. I have a shape, and I would like to give it a "pixelated" look, a bit like the letter Y below (in contrast to the B letter, which is not pixelated).

[image]

How can I do this (apart from 100% manually) please?

**EDIT:**
I realized, reading @billiy Kerr's answer, that my question was not phrased properly.

Taking the "BYT" word as an example, I would like to pixelate *only* one of the letters, not the others. This makes the task more difficult since it means I can't take e.g., a bitmap font (as Billy suggested). If I did, then all the characters would be pixelated.

So, starting with a a regular font, is there any way to pixelate some character in this font?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but how do you come to the conclusion that the "T" is not 'pixelated'?

Comment: @usr2564301 well observed. I changed the pic.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do anything manually, you could find a bitmap font, perhaps like this one called "Upheaval" by Ænigma, from Dafont. They have quite a few to choose from.

[image]

Comment: thanks for this answer. Unfortunately I was not v. clear in the first place. I edited my question correspondingly.